# How to redirect an "a href" to a tab in an other page

Tags: html

I want to use a link to redirect me, when I click it, to a tab in another page.
Here is my link

```
<a href="profile.php#patientsTab" role="button" class="green" > Click here to add New Patient and Go To Patients Tab </a>
```

And here is the tab in the other page that i want to go to:

```
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#patients" id="patientsTab">
    <i class="blue ace-icon fa fa-users bigger-120"></i>
    Patients
</a>
```

I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: And where are the links? PS: edit your post don't put it in comment.

Comment: @Butterfly Are you using an HTML/CSS/JS framework, such as Bootstrap?

Comment: yes i am using bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Add a target="_blank" to direct them to a new tab.

```
  <a href="profile.php#patientsTab" role="button" target="_blank" class="green" > Click here to add New Patient and Go To Patients Tab </a>
```

Comment: i don't want to open link in another tab in fact.